# Winsock 2 WSAPROTOCOL_INFO struct

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock2

I have written a little program to get the supported socket types of Windows. I've tried to output the szProtocol member, but always get an empty string or "r". Does anybody know if do something wrong?
I compiled it with mingw: `gcc socket.c -o socket.exe -lws2_32`

**My Code:**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE 1
#endif
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#endif
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
WSADATA data;
//WCHAR Guid[40] = {0};
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &data) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed!\r\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFO buffer = malloc(16384);
    DWORD lngt =0;
    lngt = 32000;
    int ret = 0;
    int retI = 0;
    ret = WSAEnumProtocols(NULL,buffer,&lngt);
    if(ret != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"Enum suceeded with %d protocols!r\n",ret);
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<ret;i++) {
            wprintf(L"Provider Entry number %d\n",i);
            wprintf(L"---------------------------\n");
            wprintf(L"Entry type:\t\t\t");
            if(buffer[i].ProtocolChain.ChainLen==1) {
                wprintf(L"Base Service Provider\n");
            } else {
                wprintf(L"Layered Chain Entry\n");
            }
            if(buffer[i].szProtocol != 0) {
            wprintf(L"Protocol (maybe API bug):\t\t");
            //wprintf(L"%ls: %d\n",L"Unkown",buffer[i].szProtocol);
                wprintf(L"%ws\n",buffer[i].szProtocol);
            } else { wprintf(L"Protocol: NONE\n"); }

            // Address Family
            wprintf(L"Address Family:\t\t\t");
            switch(buffer[i].iAddressFamily) {
            case AF_INET:
            wprintf(L"IPv4\n");
            break;
            case AF_IPX:
            wprintf(L"IPX\n");
            break;
            case AF_APPLETALK:
            wprintf(L"AppleTalk\n");
            break;
            case AF_NETBIOS:
            wprintf(L"Netbios\n");
            case AF_INET6:
            wprintf(L"IPv6\n");
            break;
            case AF_IRDA:
            wprintf(L"Infrared Data Association\n");
            break;
            case 32:
            wprintf(L"Bluetooth\n");
            break;
            }

            // Socket Type
            switch(buffer[i].iSocketType) {
                case SOCK_STREAM:
                case SOCK_DGRAM:
                case SOCK_RAW:
                case SOCK_RDM:
                case SOCK_SEQPACKET:
                break;
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        WSACleanup();
        free(buffer);
        exit(0);
    } else {
    WSACleanup();
    free(buffer);
    exit(1);
    }
}
```

**The output:**

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>socket
Enum suceeded with 9 protocols!r
Provider Entry number 0
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):
Address Family:                 IPv4


Provider Entry number 1
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):
Address Family:                 IPv4


Provider Entry number 2
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):
Address Family:                 IPv6


Provider Entry number 3
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):
Address Family:                 IPv6


Provider Entry number 4
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):               r
Address Family:                 IPv6


Provider Entry number 5
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):               r
Address Family:                 IPv4


Provider Entry number 6
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):               r
Address Family:                 IPv6


Provider Entry number 7
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):               r
Address Family:                 IPv4


Provider Entry number 8
---------------------------
Entry type:                     Base Service Provider
Protocol (maybe API bug):
Address Family:                 Bluetooth
```

Comment: Move `#define UNICODE 1` *before* the #includes.

Comment: But why does the includes need the definition of `UNICODE`? The data types are always WCHAR*. I thought wchar is an UNICODE character.

Comment: He's calling WSAEnumProtocolsA(), the ANSI version, because of the misplaced #define.

Comment: Oh WSAEnumProtocols is only a macro, I thought it is a function.

Comment: `WSAEnumProtocolsA()` and `WSAEnumProtocolsW()` are functions.  `WSAEnumProtocols()` is a macro that calls one or the other depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.